# Need help identifying this 6-pin surface-mount component marked L1t or L1-

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

I have a device with a small chip that needs to be replaced. On one of my devices the chip reads "L1t" on it, and on another one of the same kind of device it reads "L1-".

They should be interchangeable because they are used in the same place on the PCB. I assume one is just an older version than the other.
I have found other similar looking things online labeled microcontroller or semiconductor, but nothing that has the Lt1 or Lt- on it.

Can anyone identify this part?

[image: Photo of PCB with 10 of the unknown component marked by red ring]

[image: Close-up photo showing 4 of the unknown component]

Comment: What are they hooked up to? Knowing that would help determine their probable purpose and thus what class of component we're looking for here. The - or T is probably a date code or factory code, indicating when or where it was made.

Comment: The device is a wired controller. It has a membrane switch pad that connects to the PCB with a ribbon cable that plugs into the wide tan piece above the chips. From that plug, the traces go through the Lt- chips and down to the chips labeled "103". When one of these chips are blown, a function on the membrane pad no longer will work.

Comment: Given that they are close to an external connector, they are probably ESD protection diodes.  One pin probably goes to the power supply while the others all connect to the datalines of the connector.

Comment: would any ESD protection diode with 6 pins probably work to replace these then? Or should I keep searching for one that has the matching L1t/L1- label?

Comment: [PESD3V3L4UG](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2207151730_TECH-PUBLIC-PESD3V3L4UG_C3021134.pdf) from Tech Public Taiwan.

Comment: @hcheung - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However please don't answer a question in a comment, as that is not one of the few [allowed uses of comments](/help/privileges/comment) and (mis)using comments that way causes several problems. || If you believe that you have the answer to the question, then please post an actual answer instead. However note that the device you linked uses a 5-pin SOT-323 (SC70-5) package, but the OP's photo shows a 6-pin package. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

These components are [BAT754L](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BAT754L.pdf) from Nexperia.

Picture from [LCSC](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Schottky-Barrier-Diodes-SBD_Nexperia-BAT754L-115_C272176.html) :

[image]